# Passed prop to vue-router is not set immediately

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have set up my vue-router like so:

```
<router-view action="/test"></router-view>
```

In one of my router components I have set up a prop like this:

```
props: {
    action: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    }
}
```

But this results in an error:

> vue.esm.js:574 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "action"

If I simply echo out the action inside my template it has been set though and the vue devtools look fine:

```
{{ action }}
```

It seems the prop simply does not reach the component fast enough for the initial required check.

Am I wrong to assume this should simply work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote

Bind data with the colon`:`. Change your `router tag`  to

```
<router-view :action="'/test'"></router-view>
```

Comment: Does not matter this results in the same error. Besides data binding is only neccesary with javascript variables not primitive strings.

Comment: Nevermind I dun goofed up, I have another instance of my router-view where it was not set yet. My example works. Can't delete my question because you have already placed an answer.

Comment: @Stephan-v :  can you share small live demo ?